# How to add li elements with a text in between existing li list using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 8 li elements with each having value from 1 to 8.

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="even">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="even">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li class="even">6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li class="even">8</li>
</ul>
```

I want to insert li with text 'I am above x' above every li with even value. The desired li should look like

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>This is above 2</li>
  <li class="even">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>This is above 4</li>
  <li class="even">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>This is above 6</li>
  <li class="even">6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>This is above 8</li>
  <li class="even">8</li>
</ul>
```

This can't be hardcoded as i have simplified the problem. Actually i want to dynamically add html above specific li elements.

I tried using `.insertBefore()` but this is not working.

```
("<li>x</li>").insertBefore$('#listing li.even');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child()` selector like this.

```
$('li:nth-child(even)').each(function() {
    var num = $(this).text();
  $(this).before('<li> This is before '+ num +'</li>');
})
```

```js
$('li:nth-child(even)').each(function() {
  var num = $(this).text();
  $(this).before('<li> This is before ' + num + '</li>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="even">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="even">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li class="even">6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li class="even">8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`:even`](https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selector that select element has even index and use [`.before( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) to insert html before selected element. `.before()` is a good alternative instead `.each()` if you want to insert html in loop.

```
$("li:gt(0):even").before(function(i, text){
    return "<li>This is above " + text + "</li>";
});
```

```js
$("li:gt(0):even").before(function(i, text){
    return "<li>This is above " + text + "</li>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="even">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="even">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li class="even">6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li class="even">8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, it's because the syntax is way off.

```
$("<li>x</li>").insertBefore($('#listing li.even'));
```

The `$` in the beginning is just a shorthand for jQuery's wrapping function, which returns a jQuery object. Without it, you are trying to call `insertBefore` on a string value `"<li>x</li>"`. Strings don't have the `insertBefore` function, jQuery objects do.

Also, you have `insertBefore$('...')`. `insertBefore` is a function, `insertBefore$` is not. You are trying to call `insertBefore$` on a string, but what you *really* want is to call `insertBefore` on a jQuery object.

Also, technically in the provided fiddle `#listing` doesn't exist, but I kept in it because I assume it exists on the page in question?

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each($("#listid").find("li:odd"), function () {
        $(this).before("<li>This is above " + $(this).text() + "</li>");
    });
});
```

Working code: https://jsfiddle.net/n3tzf2pd/7/

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
<html>
    <script>
        function generate(num) {

            var text = "<ul>";

            for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                text += "<li>text: " + i + "</li>";
            }

            text += "<ul>";

            var div = document.getElementById("your_div");
            div.innerHTML = text;

        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <div id="your_div"></div>
        <input type="button" onclick="generate(8)" value="Generate" />
    </body>
</html>
```